# Azure Java SDK for blob - A request was made to load the default HttpClient provider but one could not be found on the classpath

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A request was made to load the default HttpClient provider but one could not be found on the classpath. If you are using a dependency manager, consider including a dependency on azure-core-http-netty or azure-core-http-okhttp. Depending on your existing dependencies, you have the choice of Netty or OkHttp implementations. Additionally, refer to https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/docs/custom-httpclient to learn about writing your own implementation.
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:37)
at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:27)
at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:60)
at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.BuilderHelper.buildPipeline(BuilderHelper.java:110)
at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:107)
at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:84)
```

Comment: error thrown by: BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint("https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net").buildClient();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/core/azure-core/src/main/java/com/azure/core/implementation/http/HttpClientProviders.java) will occur when failing to find HttpClient. It seems not related to the code. Try to check if you follow the steps in the documentation.

I try the following code in App.java and it works well.

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
```

[image]

If deleting the `credential()`, it will return this error: *ResourceNotFound The specified resource does not exist*.

Access public blob without credential:

[image]

Comment: https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/iris.csv is public so I want to access without credential

Comment: I also tried to access public blob without credential, it also works. I edit the reply to add the screenshot. Plz share the steps that you follow, and it's better to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

it works:

take https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-java-storage-blob-upload-download

change azure versions in pom to 12.9

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=azuremlexamples

edit as below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Writer;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.common.StorageSharedKeyCredential;

public class Quickstart {
    static File createTempFile() throws IOException {

        // Here we are creating a temporary file to use for download and upload to Blob
        // storage
        File sampleFile = null;
        sampleFile = File.createTempFile("sampleFile", ".txt");
        System.out.println(">> Creating a sample file at: " + sampleFile.toString());
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sampleFile));
        output.write("Hello Azure Storage blob quickstart.");
        output.close();

        return sampleFile;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Creating a sample file to use in the sample
        File sampleFile = null;
        sampleFile = createTempFile();
        String downloadedFilePath = "downloadedFile.txt";

        // Retrieve the credentials and initialize SharedKeyCredentials
        String accountName = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT");
        String accountKey = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY");
        String endpoint = "https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
        String containerName = "datasets";
        String blobName = "iris.csv";

        // Create a SharedKeyCredential
        //StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
       
        // Create a blobServiceClient
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .buildClient();

        // Create a containerClient
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Create a container
//        blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
  //      System.out.printf("Creating a container : %s %n", blobContainerClient.getBlobContainerUrl());

        // Create a BlobClient to run operations on Blobs
    //    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

                System.out.println("Listing blobs in the container: " + blobContainerClient.getBlobContainerUrl());
                blobContainerClient.listBlobs()
                        .forEach(
                            blobItem -> System.out.println("This is the blob name: " + blobItem.getName()));
        }
    }
```

run mvn compile exec:java

output is:

Listing blobs in the container: https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets
This is the blob name: criteo-uplift-v2.1.csv.gz
This is the blob name: iris.csv